# TypeScript infer the 'never' type in accumulator object when reducing an Array of object keys

Tags: typescript, object, reduce

```
const getObjectKeys = Object.keys as <T extends object>(obj: T) => Array<keyof T>;

interface AB {
    a: string;
    b: number;
}
export function test(config: AB) {
    Utils.getObjectKeys(config).reduce((memo, key) => {
        **memo[key]** = config[key];
        return memo;
    }, {} as AB);
}
```

memo[key] - TS2322: Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.

It's only working if i rewrite it like (memo as any)[key]. Why i can't use it like this in typescript? How to initialize accumulator memo to fix this problem?

Comment: `const getObjectKeys = Object.keys as (obj: T) => Array;` is incorrect syntax

Comment: Why not just `return Object.assign({}, config)` ?

Comment: Or `return { ...config }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler unfortunately can't follow the logic of the single line `memo[key] = config[key]` when `key` is of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) like `keyof AB`. It doesn't analyze that line by paying attention to the *identities* of the variables; it just looks at the *types*.  But the only reason we know `memo[key] = config[key]` is okay is because the *identical* `key` is used on both sides.  If we had `key1` and `key2`, both of type `keyof AB`, then the compiler's analysis would be more reasonable.

That analysis is implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769).  Given  `memo[key1] = config[key2]`, the compiler knows that reading from `config[key2]` where `key2` is a union results in another union, `string | number`.  But assigning to `memo[key1]` is possibly unsafe.  After all, `key1` and `key2` might be different members of the union. The only way for such an assignment to be safe is if `config[key2]` would be assignable to `memo[key1]` no matter what `key1` was.  That would mean `config[key2]` would have to be *both* a `string` *and* a `number`: that is, the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `string & number`.  But there is no value of that type; it's impossible.  And so the compiler collapses that intersection to [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  So the compiler would rightly complain that `memo[key1] = config[key2]` is an error, since, without knowing what `key1` is, you can't safely assign anything to it.  Such analysis is generally useful and catches real errors.

Unfortunately, when you have `key` instead of `key1` and `key2`, then the compiler is overly cautious, since it's worried about the impossible event that you're assigning a `string` to a `number` or vice versa.

---

So what can we do?  From [a comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769#issuecomment-498428559) from the implementer of ms/TS#30769, it is apparent that the way to make TypeScript follow the intended logic is to make `key`'s type a [*generic*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `K` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to a union instead of a union itself.  That is, you make the [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) callback generic as follows:

```
function test(config: AB) {
    getObjectKeys(config).reduce(<K extends keyof AB>(memo: AB, key: K) => {
        memo[key] = config[key];
        return memo;
    }, {} as AB);
}
```

This works because both sides of the assignment are seen as the generic type `AB[K]`.  It turns out that this is actually unsafe in the same way as with a union one would be (you could make `key1` and `key2` of type `K`, and make `K` the full union `keyof AB`, and it would be allowed).  But, as said in that comment, TypeScript admits certain types of unsafe behavior, and assignments between identical *generic* indexed access types are allowed.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygeQEYCsHCgaQQTwhgF4Y1NsA6AawKIEMiAeAFRgQA8oEwATIkBixQAfAApB6AFwwWAShIiYAQQBOq+via18IAGayRAbgCwAKHMBLMN1V76wBCoBCMAN7mYXmPRnRV1nCmZt4wqDJgAK4AtqgIqsEAvuacAA4gqrB6kWDYluAw3NBioGB6lnAyys4KHiHeiChC2HiEJeDlcHKUqgi8kY5iTDjsXDz8MDr6LuLRCNEgVc4ANJMEMjgKxEp1oaFzCwDaOgC6JDClnccEJ8F73r1QkapgMAcgd96Jq26JPkTVORJIA)